# Tag based search using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a website which will allow users to search products based on tags. These tags will also power the auto completion. There can be multiple tags associated with product.

What is best way to map tags in elastic search for this kind this kind of scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a field in your type mapping set up as a [`keyword` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) to be used for aggregations and sorting; this field can accept an array of tag strings.

Have a separate index and type to power autocompletion of tags with A [`completion` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-suggesters-completion.html#completion-suggester-mapping) to be used for autocompletion; this field accepts an object that includes an `input`array of strings.

Comment: How to aggregate the documents based on tags ? For example, if I want to group the documents based on tags